# Uso de la palabra "matado" en artículo periodístico

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, sintaxis, redacción

Estaba leyendo el siguiente artículo periodístico:

> [Un jurado de Nueva York exonera al policía del ‘caso Garner’](http://internacional.elpais.com/internacional/2014/12/03/actualidad/1417637204_665433.html).

Cuando encontré la siguiente frase:

> ...cuando otro gran jurado absolvió al agente Darren Wilson, que había **matado** a tiros al adolescente negro Michael Brown...

En mi opinión, la palabra **matado** es incorrecta, sin embargo, encuentro difícil argumentar del porqué es así.

Considero que en lugar de la palabra **matado** se debería emplear alguna de las siguientes alternativas:

- Asesinado.
- Ultimado.
- Eliminado.

<sub>Estas son sólo algunas palabras, pero puede que existan otras palabras mas acordes.</sub>

*Si es posible dejar a una lado el posible error del periodista (o la persona que haya redactado la noticia),* mi pregunta es:

**¿La palabra *matado* es correcta?**

Comment: "Eliminar" a alguien a tiros es jerga de mafiosos. Es sacarse un problema de encima. Un periodista no lo usaría, menos hablando de un adolescente negro.

Comment: Creo que también se puede decir que se lo han "cargado" o que lo han "finado" (este último no se usa en España). Hay un montón de jerga para "despachar" a alguien.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Matar*  (bueno, su participio *matado*) me parece la mejor opción.  *Asesinar* y *eliminar* conllevan sentidos de premeditación o intento, y por tanto culpabilidad (que legalmente según el jurado, no había).  *Matar* como verbo es neutro, simplemente nos explica que, por una acción suya, está muerto alguien.

Yo no he escuchado *ultimar* en este contexto, pero según el DRAE, es americanismo y según el DAA, se usa en todo el continente excepto Colombia, Guatemala, Venezuela y las partes no orientales de Bolivia.  No obstante, *El País* es un periódico español, y ya que el único verbo aceptable en España en este contexto es *matar* (por carecer de otra palabra sencilla neutra en esa tierra), han usado *matado*.

Comment: En Chile los periodistas usan mucho "ultimar". Es de esas palabras que se vuelven prestigiosas y dan a entender que se es muy culto. En el resto de los casos tu respuesta refleja exactamente el uso en Chile.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo. Es uno de esos casos en que el delito es [homicidio](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homicidio) y no asesinato "El homicidio se diferencia del asesinato por su carencia de alevosía, ensañamiento u otras circunstancias".

Comment: "Ultimar" en España estoy seguro de no haberlo oído en ese sentido jamás; se suele decir cuando se está acabando algún trabajo o algunos preparativos. «Estaban ultimando los detalles del proyecto», por ejemplo.

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta de guifa me parece correcta.

Es verdad que la palabra "matado" puede sonar un poco fuerte, en ese contexto. Porque "matar" pone el énfasis en una acción plenamente intencionada, con un fin deliberado. Pero, en este sentido, las alternativas que enumera la pregunta no son mejores.

Si se desea dar una versión algo más neutral o benévola, podríamos decir:

> ... que había disparado al adolescente negro Michael Brown,
>   ocasionándole la muerte.

La diferencia puede resultar más notable si se piensa en muertes claramente culposas: decir "Juan mató a su amigo Pedro al escapársele accidentalmente un disparo de su escopeta de caza"... es un poco fuerte. Más natural es decir "provocó la muerte" u "ocasionó la muerte".

Comment: En España no usamos el verbo *matar* en forma pasiva. Además, como @guifa indica en su respuesta, la palabra *asesinado* tiene unas implicaciones que se darían en este caso (*a sangre fría*), pero no se cumplen en el otro.